# Swagger Spring Annotations: proper response formatting

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I have Swagger code annotations for documentation purposes similar to the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/campaigns/{campaignUuid}",
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation(value = "...",
              httpMethod = "GET",
              notes = "...",
              response = XCampaign.class,
              tags = { "Campaigns" })
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200,
                                     message = "OK",
                                     response = XCampaign.class),
                        @ApiResponse(code = 401,
                                     message = "Unauthorized",
                                     response = HttpErrorResponse.class),
                        @ApiResponse(code = 400,
                                     message = "Bad Request",
                                     response = HttpErrorResponse.class),
                        @ApiResponse(code = 404,
                                     message = "Not Found",
                                     response = HttpErrorResponse.class),
                        @ApiResponse(code = 500,
                                     message = "Internal Server Error",
                                     response = HttpErrorResponse.class) })
```

Basically, I want to have the following responses documented in Swagger:

On 200:

```
{
    'campaign': {
        ...
    },
    links: {
        ...
    }
}
```

On 4xx or 5xx:

```
{
    error: {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is the "nested" component. If I list the class itself as the `Response` class, it is obviously not given back as nested JSON. If I try to nest it however, like follows:

```
public class HttpErrorResponse {

    private ErrorResponse error;

    private class ErrorResponse {
        public final String code;
        public final String message;

        public ErrorResponse(String code, String message) {
            this.code = code;
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the Swagger Docs show an empty Object:

`HttpErrorResponse {}`

I've also taken a look at Spring HATEOAS, and think that I will be able to achieve the 2xx Response type using that, how can I achieve what I want in general with nested types?

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your `Docket`

```
.alternateTypeRules(
        newRule(typeResolver.resolve(DeferredResult.class,
                typeResolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class)),
            typeResolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))
```

Which substitutes `DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<T>>` with `T` generically, for more info see the useful guid for how to configure Swagger [here](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#configuring-springfox-staticdocs).

Also import all required lib, including the one which is tricky to figure out:

```
import static springfox.documentation.schema.AlternateTypeRules.*;
```